# Как убрать регистрозависимость при получении данных из БД?

Tags: c#, postgresql

Использую EF Core и мне нужно получить запись по имени.

Запрос

```
    public async Task<T> GetAnimalByNameAsync(string animalName)
    {
        return await _dataContext.Set<T>()
            .Include(x => x.Breed)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name.Equals(animalName));
    }
```

Контекст БД

```
    public DbSet<Breed> AnimalBreeds { get; set; }

    public DbSet<AnimalEntity> Animals { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Food> Foods { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Feeding> Feedings { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.UseCollation("Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");
        modelBuilder.UseCollation("Cyrillic_General_CI_AS");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Breed>().Property(e => e.Type)
            .HasConversion(
            x => x.ToString(),
            v => (AnimalType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AnimalType), v));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Cat>().Property(e => e.Type)
            .HasConversion(
            x => x.ToString(),
            v => (AnimalType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AnimalType), v));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().Property(e => e.Type)
            .HasConversion(
            x => x.ToString(),
            v => (AnimalType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AnimalType), v));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Food>().Property(e => e.Type)
            .HasConversion(
            x => x.ToString(),
            v => (AnimalType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AnimalType), v));
    }
```

При создании миграции получаю исключение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Базу данных использую Postgresql

Comment: Указанные collation используются в Sql Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В первую очередь, надо убедиться что вы правильно задаете имя Collation. Используйте следующий запрос для того чтобы получить список предустановленных Collation в вашей системе:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_collation
```

Во вторых, следует помнить, что поддержка регистро-независимых локалей появилась лишь в PostgreSQL 12. В старых версиях чтобы оперировать с данными игнорируя регистр следовало назначить колонке специальный тип `citext`.

```cs
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "citext")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Источники:
[PostgreSQL: Collation Support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html)
[Entity Framework Core: Collations and case sensitivity, The citext type](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/misc/collations-and-case-sensitivity.html#the-citext-type)

Comment: modelBuilder.UseCollation("CREATE COLLATION russian (LOCALE = 'ru-RU')");
Не подскажете почему это не работает? При update-database возникает ошибка 42809: неверное имя локали: "CREATE COLLATION russian (LOCALE = 'ru-RU')"

Comment: Судя по ошибке, EF использует параметр метода UseCollation как имя локали, а вы задали SQL выражение.

Comment: Всё разобрался, заработало)